# Load form's controls to panel in C#

Tags: c#, controls, panel

I want to load Form's controls to a panel in C# so the panel will show the same components as the form. I have tried this code:

```
foreach (Control control in (new Form2()).Controls)
{
    panels[panelsCounter].Controls.Add(control);
}
```

But the problem is that when I'm running the program it loads only the type of control that I've added last (For example if I've been added a label and than I've added a button to the form it shows only a button, but if I add another label, it shows both of the labels, but not the button).

Please help me.

Comment: You're not setting location. Are the locations pre set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic bug, you are modifying the collection while you are iterating it.  The side-effect is that only ever other control will be moved to the panel.  You'll need to do this carefully, iterate the collection backwards to avoid the problem:

```
var formObj = new Form2();    //???
for (int ix = formObj.Controls.Count-1; ix >= 0; --ix) {
    panels[panelsCounter].Controls.Add(formObj.Controls[ix]);
}
```

Comment: Hans, In that case it should have thrown `InvalidOperationException` right?

Comment: No, not every collection type implements that check.  Control.ControlCollection doesn't.

Comment: *You're great man*, Am sorry, i can't upvote you. I upvoted already SO is not allowing me to do :(

Comment: Can you pls tell how did you gain this much knowledge?

Comment: It is hair thing, grey beard and nothing on top :)

Answer (score 0):

Controls are not designed to be displayed multiple times.  You cannot add controls to multiple forms, or add the same control to a form multiple times.  They simply weren't designed to support it.

You could go through each control and create a new control of the same type, and even copy over the values of their properties (or at least what's publicly accessible to you), effectively cloning them, but it's important that it be a different control that you add to the new panel.

Comment: You can see OP is creating `new Form2()` and adding its controls to panel, that shouldn't be a problem, controls will be removed from Form and added to Panel. He's not removing from existing instance

Comment: @SriramSakthivel But he's *not* removing the controls from the form.  He's leaving them in both places.  They're not built to support that.  For example, what will `control.Parent` contain?  It can't have two parents.  The idea of having a control in two containers is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: Nope, IIRC then adding a control which is parented by another will automatically remove from previous parent and adds it to next parent. So that shouldn't be a problem(though it is not a good idea and looks ugly)

Comment: `control.Parent` will contain new `Parent` try it out